# Merging huge sets (HashSet) in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I have two huge (as in millions of entries) sets (HashSet) that have some (<10%) overlap between them. I need to merge them into one set (I don't care about maintaining the original sets).

Currently, I am adding all items of one set to the other with:

```
setOne ++= setTwo
```

This takes several minutes to complete (after several attempts at tweaking hashCode() on the members).

Any ideas how to speed things up?

Comment: These are mutable sets, right?

Comment: What do you do with the merged set afterwards? What operations and how many? (I'm thinking you could take a lazy approach and not bother merging the sets at all if there a small number of things you will do with it - just do the op on one or both sets as appropriate)

Comment: Do you know if the performance is impacted by memory heap size? Sometimes when the JVM runs out of heap, performance is degraded as the garbage collector spend all its time reclaiming memory.

Comment: @huynhjl Your point is valid. I did run into severe degradation initially, but fixed it by applying flyweight to the set members.

Comment: @Paul: in this particular case I just save the sets to a text file, so this will work. However, the point of this question is to actually find ways to improve the merging of large sets....

Comment: @Daniel: yes, they are scala.collection.mutable.HashSet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get slightly better performance with Parallel Collections API in Scala 2.9.0+:

```
setOne.par ++ setTwo
```

or

```
(setOne.par /: setTwo)(_ + _)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you might wanna try:

- Use the `sizeHint` method to keep your sets at the expected size.
- Call `useSizeMap(true)` on it to get better hash table resizing.

It seems to me that the latter option gives better results, though both show improvements on tests here.

Comment: That's generally useful. Unfortunately I'm doing a brute-force search and have no idea what the size of the individual sets will be; at least not until I've calculated them...

Comment: @Alexandros You could always call `size` on each collection and estimate the size of the merge. Or use `useSizeMap`, which does not require you to tell it anything.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me a little more about the data inside the sets? The reason I ask is that for this kind of thing, you usually want something a bit specialized. Here's a few things that can be done:

- If the data is (or can be) sorted, you can walk pointers to do a merge, similar to what's done using merge sort. This operation is pretty trivially parallelizable since you can partition one data set and then partition the second data set using binary search to find the correct boundary.
- If the data is within a certain numeric range, you can instead use a bitset and just set bits whenever you encounter that number.
- If one of the data sets is smaller than the other, you could put it in a hash set and loop over the other dataset quickly, checking for containment.

I have used the first strategy to create a gigantic set of about 8 million integers from about 40k smaller sets in about a second (on beefy hardware, in Scala).